# Omnet++5.0: Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm beginner at omnet++ and veins, I have just installed Omnet++ 5.0 (on Windows 10) and installed INET with it as well. I've added a new application traci named "obstacle"  to block véhicules, I've changed the files `erlangen.launchd.xml` and `omnetpp.ini` and I try to run the examples erlangen. However, it throws an error:

> Simulation terminated with exit code: -1073741819.

I am not finding any help regarding this error anywhere.
Please help me .

Answer (score 1):

`-1073741819` is equal to `0xC0000005`. Try to search using this error number.
Moreover, take a look at [Debugging](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part2/) and set in your `omnetpp.ini`:

```
 debug-on-errors = true
```

Thanks to that when your simulation crashes, the debugger will show the line that is source of this error.

Answer (score 0):

the debugger open cexecption.cc

[the result of debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JChxn.png)

and the error message is :

std::logic_error: basic_string::_m_construct null not valid -- in module (veins::traciscenariomanagerlaunchd) rsuexamplescenario.manager (id=6), at t=1s, event #2

Comment: Click "More frames..." to find the line from your model that causes an error.

Comment: *********** omnetpp::cRuntimeError::notifyEnvir (this=0x66a5a8) at cexception.cc:260
260 } ********** but i didn't touch this file    : cRuntimeError::cRuntimeError(const char *msgformat...)
{
    va_list va;
    va_start(va, msgformat);
    init(nullptr, E_CUSTOM, msgformat, va);
    va_end(va);
    notifyEnvir();
}